# iText: how to add a blank line with controlled height

Tags: itext

I am new to iText. I use iText 5.5.3.

I researched and applied what I found regarding adding a blank line. For example

```
method 1:
document.add( Chunk.NEWLINE );

method 2:
document.add( new Phrase("\n") );
```

However, I notice that the height of blank lines are too big. How can I reduce it?

Thanks and regards.

Answer (score 0):

I know using tables for page layout was abandoned in the 90s, but I find using tables with iTextSharp often offers a great level of precision.

```
document.Add(BlankLineDoc(16));

public static PdfPTable BlankLineDoc(int height)
{
    var table = new PdfPTable(1) {WidthPercentage = 100};
    table = BlankLineTable(table, height);
    return table;
}

public static PdfPTable BlankLineTable(PdfPTable table, int height, int border = Rectangle.NO_BORDER)
{
    var cell = new PdfPCell(new Phrase(" "))
    {
        Border = border,
        Colspan = table.NumberOfColumns,
        FixedHeight = height
    };
    table.AddCell(cell);
    return table;
}
```

`BlankLineTable` can be used directly when working with tables.

Answer (score 0):

You can set height of blank lines like this :

```
 PdfPTable table2 = new PdfPTable(1);
    table2.getDefaultCell().setBorder(0);
    table2.getDefaultCell().setPadding(0);
    table2.setWidthPercentage(100);
    table2.getDefaultCell().setHorizontalAlignment(Element.ALIGN_CENTER);
    addBlankLines(table2, 3 ,10);
document.add(table2);

public PdfPTable addBlankLines(PdfPTable table, int noOfLine , float height) {
    table.getDefaultCell().setFixedHeight(height);
    for (int i = 0; i < noOfLine; i++) {
        table.addCell(" ");
    }
    return table;
}
```